# Excel expand text horizontally down instead of vertically to the right

Tags: vba, excel

The default behavior is that text overflows to the right into the next cells, is there a way to change this to make the text flow downward to cells below the same way as it flows to the right?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the cell and choose the Format option.  Click on the Alignment tab.  You can change the Horizontal Text alignment to Fill.  Only the text that fits will be displayed, the overflow will be hidden.

Or, you can check the Wrap text box, the text will wrap vertically increasing the height of the cell.

I see no option to overflow down.

Comment: That is a shame, because it would really alleviate the presentation of some data if I could overflow down.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know of is to merge the cells vertically.  Merge enough cells and you will reveal all of the text.  Brute force approach, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest settings that you have to keep in cell alignment tab.
here is how you can make sure the settings should look like.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please add some explanation and quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Select your desired cell, apply the Wrap Text effect (which can be found in the [Home menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgho3.png)), then drag the borders of the cell as you please.